# Is it possible to connect to another linux machine that uses the same internet?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking

I'm new to the whole `ssh` thing so I don't have a big idea of it.

From my linux laptop, I can connect to my school's internet by typing

`ssh <school username>@<school.edu>`
... then it proceeds to ask me my school account password.

I have a laptop and a desktop (both run linux), that use the same internet. I want to connect from my laptop to my desktop. The only part is I don't know what to put for the `<school username>@<school.edu>` part of it. To connect, do I need to buy a host? How do I connect from laptop to my desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can do that.

The long answer is, if you did not know you can do that, then it is possible that `sshd` is not running your desktop PC yet.

**How to check for `sshd`**:

- In a terminal on the Desktop, type `ps auxwww | grep sshd`.
- If you get something like `... /usr/sbin/sshd` then you have sshd installed and running. Move on to how to connect part. If not, install `sshd` using your package manager.

**Install `sshd` or Openssh Server (if needed)**. In most current Linux versions typing `sshd` in a terminal will let you know what to do. At a guess it will be something like:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

After the install on the Desktop you should be able to connect from the Laptop to the Desktop.

**Connecting to the Desktop over `ssh`**. You need to know either the name of your Desktop on the local network or the IP. I'm going with the IP in this example as it is a more certain way to connect. From the Laptop, type:

```
ssh <desktop user name>@<ip of desktop>
```

If your `username` is the same on the Laptop and the Desktop, you can drop the `username` part. For example:

```
ssh <ip of desktop>
```

If your Desktop has a network name (lets call it "desktop") and you can `ping` it, you should be able to replace the IP with the network name. For example:

```
ssh desktop
```

And if you want skip the password entry, you need to look in to `ssh-keygen`. But that is another topic really :]

Comment: Thank you! I did look into ssh-keygen and now I can log in without password ;) thanks alot for your help to take the time and write all this